# Why does this generic code compile?

Tags: java, generics

Javac infers that `T` is `String` in method `f()`. Which rules in language spec lead to that conclusion?

```
<T> T g(){ return null; }

String f()
{
    return g();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the compiler is effectively using [section 15.12.2.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.8):

> If the method result occurs in a context where it will be subject to assignment conversion (§5.2) to a type S, then let R be the declared result type of the method

This is treating the return statement as if it were subject to assignment conversion. For example, imagine we converted `f()` to:

```
String f()
{
    String tmp = g();
    return tmp;
}
```

Now as to whether it *is* subject to assignment conversion, [section 14.17](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.17) (the return statement) contains this:

> A return statement with an Expression must be contained in a method declaration that is declared to return a value (§8.4) or a compile-time error occurs. The Expression must denote a variable or value of some type T, or a compile-time error occurs. The type T must be assignable (§5.2) to the declared result type of the method, or a compile-time error occurs.

That reference to 5.2 is the "assignment conversion" section, so I guess that means the expression `g()` *is* "subject to assignment conversion", leading to that part of section 15.12.2.8 being applicable.

Answer (score 0):

T is inferred to be a String because the generic return type of g() is used as the return type of f(), which is strongly typed to a String. In order for the statement to be valid, T must be a String, so it is.

Answer (score 0):

Because g is a generic method, Java infers the type of g to match the return type of f.

You can see this by trying the following three functions.

```
class SomeClass{

   <T> T g(){return null;}

   String f() {
      return this.<String>g();
   }

   Integer h() {
      return this.<Integer>g();
   }

   Integer i() {
      return this.<String>g();
   }
}
```

f and h will compile fine because it infers the type from the return type. i will not compile because the types do not match.